# extern "C" Vs. extern

Tags: c++, winapi

I am exporting functions from a static library as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CreateGraphicsDevice(HINSTANCE hDLL,  IAMG3DGraphicsDevice **pInterface);
}
```

All my code is written in C++, so I don't see why I need to extern "C". For example, if I put:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CreateGraphicsDevice(HINSTANCE hDLL,  IAMG3DGraphicsDevice ** pInterface)
```

the function is not accessible from the DLL. Why is extern "C" required if my code is written in c++ as opposed to putting extern directly before the function declaration?

Comment: you can and export without `extern "C"` - in this case you name will be decorated in `c++` style. and you not need `extern` keyword before  `__declspec(dllexport)`. however `the function is not accessible from the DLL` - what you mean under this ?